# Android Market - Large Package Uploads

Tags: android, upload, google-play

I see that google has introduced a means for uploading large files onto the market: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/11/io-2011-google-increases-app-size-limit-to-4gb-tweaks-the-return-policy/.

Does anyone know about this or where I can find some info on how to use this?

My app is an offline version that contains several movies and photos. This is seriously going to cause issues if I have to implement my own custom downloader for this content.

Comment: It has been released: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know about this or where I can find some info on how to use this?

AFAIK, it has not been released yet.

Comment: It seems to say that it should have been available in June last year. I sent the google guys an email so I'll post their feedback when it comes.
In the meantime if someone comes across any info, please post.

Comment: @Matthew: They were projecting a June release. They apparently missed it, by a lot.

Comment: Reply from The Android Market Team - Due to some unforeseen technical issues the app file size limit is still currently approximately 50MB. While we're working hard to increase this file size limit we cannot provide you with a estimated time-frame when this limit will be increased.

Comment: @Matthew: Well, the good news is, I was right. :-) The bad news is, I was right. :-(